# php image upload not working in landscape orientation

Tags: php, upload

I have a basic php file upload script that has been working just fine until recently. No changes have been made to the upload script. Through testing/troubleshooting, I have noticed that if the jpeg image orientation is in landscape (wider than it is high) and the file is larger than 4.5MB the download locks up at about 7% of the file being uploaded. If I rotate the image to portrait orientation and leave the file size the same, or if I reduce the image size and leave it in landscape orientation the upload goes to completion.

What has me stumped is that a larger file in portrait orientation will upload just fine, does image orientation matter when uploading a file to the server?

First I am using Javascript and AJAX to setup the upload and then call a php script. The Javascript/AJAX is:

```
function uploadFile()
    {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var location=document.getElementsByName("file");
    var file = location[0].files[0];
    formdata.append("file", file,location[0].id+"_"+date+"."+file.type.substring(file.type.indexOf("/")+1));
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    _("progressBar").style.visibility="visible";
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "as_built_replace_uploader.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
    }
```

My PHP for the upload is:

```
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file_tmp_loc = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $file_type = $_FILES["file"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $file_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $file_error_msg = $_FILES["file"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

    $wildcard="maps/".substr($filename,0,strpos($filename,"."))."*";
    foreach (glob($wildcard) as $path)
        {
        unlink($path);
        }
    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_loc,"maps/".$filename))
```

Comment: Please add php file upload script codes to your question

Comment: Considering that PHP does not even read the file during the upload I'd search elsewhere for the issue. Maybe you have a client-side library to manipulate pictures or a very picky security software somewhere in between. (I've also noticed that you read `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` but don't seem to use it—it isn't even 0 or 1 as the comment says.)

Comment: I was using $_FILES["file"]["error"] for troubleshooting in the beginning, but not currently. So are you saying the hangup is occurring during the AJAX transaction before my PHP script even starts?

Answer (score 0):

As @ÁlvaroGonzález observed, PHP *per se* does not even read the file while uploading; it doesn't even know it is a JPEG, let alone its aspect ratio.

So *someone* must be doing something with that file while it's being uploaded. Possibly we're looking at an unwanted effect of some too-clever firewall rule against some JPEG vulnerability. Try uploading the same file after prepending it with a short chunk of garbage. It will stop being a JPEG but most IDS will still "see" whatever it's inside, and react. If the upload still blocks even though the file is no longer an image, I believe it would be a strong argument for the firewall/IDS interfering.

Talking with whoever administers the upload server might also help in shedding some light.

But before doing that, are you *absolutely sure* that way larger files do upload correctly? What counts is the **encoded size**, not the original image size. Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini.